# Unable to replace matched string using python re module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My file looks like this:

---

```
[sunday]
@office 
@home 
@store

[monday]
@office
@home
@store
```

Now I need to add time before @home like this, not only @home it can be any of the three based on user input.

```
[sunday]
@office
<2016-02-02>@home
@store

[monday]
@office
<2016-02-02>@home
@store
```

> My code:

```
time= "2016-02-02"
group = "home"
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    regex = r"^@"+re.escape(group)
    for line in data:
        result =  re.findall(regex,line)
        if result:
            timeline_added = "<"+time+">"+"@"+group
            re.sub(regex, timeline_added, data)
```

I am getting

```
TypeError:expected string or buffer. I am using python 2.7
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the variable `group` a `string` ? 

`group = "home"`

`TypeError:expected string or buffer` is on which line?

Comment: @SreenadhTC same with `time`, `"file.txt"`, etc.

Comment: @ZdaR Yep, that should be the problem! Although, I think OP wants a time string, probably from `datetime` package

Comment: I edited  question guys, I missed the quotes, excuse for that

Comment: This line is still incorrect: `timeline_added = "<"+time">"+"@"+group`

Comment: Just replace the `data` with `line` in `re.sub(regex, timeline_added, data)` and you are good to go. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
time= "2016-02-02"
group = "home"
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    regex = r"^@"+re.escape(group)
    for line in data:
        result =  re.findall(regex,line)
        if result:
            timeline_added = "<"+time+">"+"@"+group
            re.sub(regex, timeline_added, line)
```

Changed data to line and it worked, based on ZdaR comment, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
time= "2016-02-02"
inp = input('Enter the input : ')
with open(r'file.txt','r') as f:
    print ('\n'.join([time+i if i.strip()=='@'+inp else i for i in f.read().split('\n')]))
```

Output:

```
Enter the input : home
[sunday]
@office 
2016-02-02@home 
@store

[monday]
@office
2016-02-02@home
@store
```

The best i got based on your requirement (in comments) is by using itertools.groupby (please look out for doc), then convert to dict with day as key and playing around with dict items.

Note : this will assume you always have a blank line between your set of day's data

```
time= "2016-02-02"
from itertools import groupby
day = input('Enter the day : ')
inp = input('Enter the input : ')
with open(r'file.txt','r') as f:
    grp = ([list(g) for k,g in groupby([i for i in f.read().split('\n')], lambda x:x=='') if not k])
    dct = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in grp}
    dct['['+day+']'] = [time+'@'+inp if inp in i else i for i in dct['['+day+']']]
    for k,v in dct.items():
        print (k + '\n' + '\n'.join(i for i in v) + '\n')
```

Output:

```
Enter the day : monday
Enter the input : store
[sunday]
@office 
@home 
@store

[monday]
@office
@home
2016-02-02@store
```

Comment: thanks Santhosh, I am just curious what if requirement says me to just add date under home based on days, like if they take input for sunday then change under sunday only not @home under Monday